# Unable to load Document from filemanager of device and external storage

Tags: android

I am new in Android Development, I am working on one functionality in android app which selects the document from Internal storage as well as external storage to load. But the code I am using to browse the files of the device is able to visible all the files in some devices but in Xiaomi devices, it is unable to visible the images files in file manager the hierarchy of the folder is FileManger->Internalstorage->pic.
The pics in the pic folder are not visible.plz, help to find the solution to the problem. Thanks in advance.

Intent Code I am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_file)), SELECT_FILE);
```

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman I think editing is not the solution to the problem.

Comment: An app cannot read another app's private data. Now, are the pdfs and images are created my your app?

Comment: No, its is not creating by my app

Comment: Then, your app cannot read another app's private data unless the other app have implemented ContentProvider. Allowing any app to access private data kind of beats the purpose of having private data then.

Comment: but I am able to read the pdf.

Comment: There is any way to read another app data

Comment: Are you able to read pdf from internal storage?

Comment: To answer 'There is any way to read another app data' - No

Comment: To answer 'Are  you able to read pdf from internal storage? '- yes

Comment: @Zaartha- So, I cannot implement the functionality by which I can select data from anywhere in the device

Comment: Not private data

Comment: Yes, I think you are right but you are but google drive able to access the file manager

Comment: Firstly, Android OS is owned by Google and so is google drive. Secondly, Google Drive comes as a system app in most of the devices. And lastly, third party apps like yours cannot read another app's private data. Let's not compare third party apps to Google apps.

Comment: @Zaartha, Could I restrict file manager folder  so that it doesn't visible as an option to others

Comment: `The pics in the pic folder are not visible.` It is unclear which folder you are talking about. Please give full path of folder. And you did not tell which app created that folder.

Comment: @blackapps -  File Manager->Internal Storage->pic this is the hierarchy of the pic folder in which images are not visible. As the above discussion, I think its privacy issue because FileManger is third another app

Comment: `File Manager->Internal Storage->pic` That does not tell anything about full path. And you did not tell which file manager. You are a programmer so please tell full path. And which file manager?

Comment: `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);` That makes no sense as you have already `intent.setType("*/*");`. Please try without.